# Cannot access memories after game completion

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I completed AC:R today and I wanted to get the remaining achievements. I read that I could access previous memories by pressing start when the credits rolled and then clicking on 'DNA'. When I click start I do not see the 'DNA' option, I only see: Resume, General, Controls and Quit.

Does anybody know how I can access the DNA menu?

Comment: Are you in the Animus when you're trying this (i.e., as Ezio, not Desmond)?

Comment: I reload my save and it goes straight to the credits, the credits also never seem to end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely need to end the credit sequence. It last around 20 minutes. But after this, no problem accessing the animus island and the game sequences. Put the credit and go for lunch.